# Finding a symmetric matrix $A$ given eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a symmetric matrix $A$ with the following eigenvalues and two of three corresponding (non-normalized) eigenvectors:

$\lambda_1 = 10, \lambda_2 = -5, \lambda_3 = -2$  and $x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \\1\end{bmatrix}, 
 x_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\-1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$.

The "third" eigenvector is unknown. I have no idea how to find the matrix $A$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: The first thing you should do is concentrate on finding the third eigenvector. What do you know about eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues of symmetric matrices (as opposed to more general matrices)?

Comment: HINT: Change of basis formula!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be nicer ways to solve this, but I'm going to solve this as if I had encountered it for the first time (as I assume you are). A symmetric 3x3 matrix has 6 free parameters. I'm going to assume you know how to solve linear systems of equations.
So lets call our matrix $A$. $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{13}&a_{23}&a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$$.
Now we get the conditions $A x_1-10 x_1=0$ and $A x_2+5 x_2=0$, which translates to a bunch of equations that we can summarize as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1\\
-2&-1&1&0&0&0\\
0&-2&0&-1&1&0\\
0&0&-2&0&-1&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}\\
a_{12}\\
a_{13}\\
a_{22}\\
a_{23}\\
a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
10\\
10\\
10\\
5\\
-5\\
\end{pmatrix}$$.
This will give you $a_{12}=-5-a_{11}$, $a_{13}=5+a_{11}$, $a_{22}=\frac{15}{2}+a_{11}$, $a_{23}=\frac{5}{2}-a_{11}$, $a_{33}=\frac{15}{2}+a_{11}$. Now we can plug all of this into our original matrix and use the last piece of information given to us, which is the characteristic polynomial. So lets Calculate $Det[A-\lambda I]=0$. this gives $(10 + 3 a_{11} - \lambda) (-50 - 5 \lambda + \lambda^2)=0$. Therefore with the condition that $\lambda_3$ is a root of this, we get $a_{11}=-4$. Thus the final matrix is
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-4&-1&1\\
-1&\frac{7}{2}&\frac{13}{2}\\
1&\frac{13}{2}&\frac{7}{2}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
And you get $$x_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: thank you for your detail explanation. The nicer way you mentioned maybe finding $x_3$ = cross product of $x_1$ and $x2$, then compute matrix $A = V \lambda V^{-1}$. I got the same result like you have above